# Getting Objects In ListBoxView To Show Different Strings?

Tags: c#, winforms, tostring

If I fill a ListBoxView with objects, the text that will display for each one will be the text produced by the ToString() function.  Let's say I want to use ToString() in some cases, and GetSpecialString() in other cases.  What is the best way to switch between the two?

Should I have two different objects with the same base class with different ToString() methods, or is there a way I can have both the ToString()  and GetSpecialString() methods in the same class?

Comment: There's ListBox or ListView, no ListBoxView.  ListBox always uses ToString() without an option to change that unless you use custom draw.  Whatever logic you use should be in the classes whose objects you add.  In their ToString override.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a class-wrapper for your view model, which returns different strings by condition:

```
class ViewModelListItem {

  public ViewModelListItem(MyObject item) {
    this.Item = item;
  }

  public MyObject Item {
    get;
    private set;
  }

  public override ToString() {
    // to do: add your logic here
    if (...)
      return "case A";
    else
      return "Case B";
  }
}
```

Then just fill your ListView with such items.

Answer (score 0):

If the choice between `ToString()` and `GetSpecialString()` is esclusive, just override `ToString()` in class you want and done.

Comment: I believe this is bad practice to unite the back-end with a view model

Comment: I'm talking about overiding to string on data model, so the call ListBox's Ite.ToString() will call appropriate override by producing desired string. OOP elegant solution, by me.